# Ionic3 and FabricJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, ionic-framework, ionic3, fabricjs

I've a big problem with Ionic3 and FabricJS. It shows me the image in the html but when i try to save it to upload to Firebase it uploads me a white screen only, like a new canvas.

This is my code

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

import 'fabric';
declare const fabric: any;

import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-filtri',
  templateUrl: 'filtri.html'
})
export class FiltriPage {

fotoModificata: any;
public fotoScelta;
itemRef : firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref('/matrimonio1');
firestore = firebase.storage();
alertCtrl: AlertController;
imgsource: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, alertCtrl: AlertController, public zone: NgZone) {

    this.alertCtrl = alertCtrl;
    this.fotoScelta = navParams.get("foto");
}


@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

goToSlide() {
      this.slides.slideTo(2, 500);
    }

ionViewDidLoad(){

  let width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
  let height = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
  let altezza = height / 100 * 60;

  canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

  canvas.setDimensions({ width: width, height: altezza});
  fabric.Image.fromURL(this.fotoScelta, function(img) {
    img.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
    canvas.add(img);
    canvas.renderAll();
    });

this.fotoModificata = canvas.toDataURL("png");

}

upload() {

    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const filename = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${filename}.png`);

    imageRef.putString(this.fotoModificata, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then((snapshot)=> {

// il codice sotto prende l'url della foto appena caricata
         this.firestore.ref().child(`images/${filename}.png`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
           this.zone.run(() => {
             this.imgsource = url;

// carica l'url in firebase.database
      let newPostRef = this.itemRef.push();
          newPostRef.set({
            "nome" : "",
            "like" : "",
            "descrizione" : "",
            "url" : url
          });


            })
         });
        this.showSuccesfulUploadAlert();

       }, (err) => { });

  }


goToHome() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }


showSuccesfulUploadAlert() {

      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Caricata!',
        subTitle: 'La foto è stata caricata!',
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();

      this.fotoModificata = "";
      //this.goToHome();

  }

}
```

`this.fotoModificata` is a variable I set for my upload function. `this.fotoScelta` is a variable that have the base64 string of my image. And this is my HTML code

```
<ion-list>
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</ion-list>
```

It prints a base64 code in the console if I ask to, but it's a blank image.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you calling this `canvas.toDataURL("png");` after image loaded or is it  shows in the function?

Comment: Yes. When I see the photo then I call toDataURL. If I use png I’ve a withe image (without background) and if I use joeg it’s black.

Comment: `canvas.toDataURL({format:"png"});` try this inside a function, call it after image loaded

Comment: Same as above.. I try also to call canvas.toDataURL in another function (button click to save) so I could trigger only when photo is loaded and it gabe me error “canvas is not a property of page” . Maybe there is something in fabric function that save toData only after image is loaded, I don’t know

Comment: this `let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');` is inside `ionViewDidLoad()` function, i guess thats y that variable canvas is not accessible to your new save function

Comment: How can I use that variable in another function? I think you are right, it try to dataURL when images isn’t loading yet

Comment: `let self = this;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(this.fotoScelta, function(img) {
      img.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
      canvas.add(img);
      canvas.renderAll();
      self.fotoModificata = canvas.toDataURL({format:"png"});
    });` check this as you dont want any modification, you can use `toDataURL` inside image load callback

Comment: It works!!! Awesome man! Write it as an answer andI'll vote! thank you!!!

Comment: edited the answer.

Comment: Can I ask you more? Because now I set another function like this ionView for apply filter and save the base 64 in this.fotoModificata but it still save the oriinal photo.

Comment: After applying filter save the canvas.

Comment: Ok the prob now is that applyFilter is async but I can use its callback.. Hope it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let self = this;
fabric.Image.fromURL(this.fotoScelta, function(img) {
  img.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
  canvas.add(img);
  canvas.renderAll();
  self.fotoModificata = canvas.toDataURL({
    format: "png"
  });
});
```

use `toDataURL` inside image load callback,so it will include image in exported png.

Comment: Ok so I’ll try as soon as possible.. but.. where I’m supposed to put “let canvas = new fabric....”? In the constructor?

Comment: @MarcoPalmisano if you are creating an object , you can initialise like `this.canvas` and access in others.

Comment: Sorry man I’m new to ionic. Where I need to put the first line of tour code “ let canvas = new fabric.Canvas(‘c’),fotoModificata;”?

Comment: can you make a snippet/fiddle with what you have till now?

Comment: I don’t know because the image comes from the cordova camera plugin and “this.fotoModificata” goes in the firebase upload function. Do you want the entire code (without che camera function that’s in the previous page)?